# How to score non-sensitive information leakage using CVSS

Tags: security

I have a task from school to do simple testing to a website which divided in multiple testing category and then score it using CVSS v3.1

On the category of Information Gathering, I found 2 vulnerabilities:

- Its manual book, which explains all capabilities of each user-roles, is publicly available. In the website, the manual is only available for admin.
- Some of its error pages is showing backend error-message, like "this error happens in X module, you can change it in blablabla". And these pages is being indexed by Google.

Now I need to score those two as one, under the category of Information Gathering, using CVSS v3.1. And this is the score that I came up with:

CVSS:3.1/AV:N/AC:H/PR:H/UI:R/S:U/C:L/I:H/A:H - Score: 6; Medium [(See calculator)](https://www.first.org/cvss/calculator/3.1#CVSS:3.1/AV:N/AC:H/PR:H/UI:R/S:U/C:L/I:H/A:H)

Personally I think the score above is not accurate (too high) because the "vulnerability" is only not-so-sensitive information leakage. So what do you think? How would you score it and why?

Additionally, when we're about to count the CVSS score of a vulnerability, how far do we have to assume about its worst possible exploitation and impact? Because I think I assume about "the worst" too far..

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You could try asking this on [security.se]. It might be on-topic there.